# Upload image with preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im in the making of creating an upload feature for forum users, so they can upload a personal picture. What i got so far:

**HTML**

```
<label>Profile image</label>
<div class="photo" id="photoPreview"></div>
<input type="file" value="forumPhoto" onchange="return changePhoto(this);">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function showPhotoPreview() {
    var photoUrl = $.trim($("#photo").val());
    var img = $("#photoPreview img");
    if (photoUrl != "") {
        if (img.length == 0) {
            img = $("<img />").appendTo($("#photoPreview"));
        }
        img.prop("src", photoUrl);
    }
    else {
        img.remove();
    }
}

function changePhoto(sender) {
    var value = $(sender).val();
    sender.selectedIndex = 0;
    switch (value) {
        case "upload":
            assignPicture();
            break;
    }
    showPhotoPreview();
    return false;
}

function assignPicture() {
    var forumPhoto = $("#forumPhoto").val();
    if (forumPhoto == "") {
        alert("You must specify an address to use forumPhoto.");
        return;
    }
    $("#photo").val(forumPhoto);
}
```

The current issue is that it doesnt show up in the preview picture.
JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qLsY7/

Comment: what doesnt work? does it fails with error or just do not do anything.

Comment: It doesn't work that way.. the `val` of an upload field will usually give you a fake path. So you need to either upload the image or load it into the browser with HTML5 fileLoader http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 1):

You will either need HTML5 (FileReader), or Flash in order to accomplish what you are looking to do. 
Simply put Javascript/iFrames have security against dealing with Local User Files and viewing them in the browser to prevent malicious use.

For a working example using Mootools 1.3.2, which you are free to convert to jQuery. I had to override the XHR method in order to handle the request, so you will more than likely need to do the same with jQuery. Notice that I do a check for FileReader and remove the ability to preview without it.

You could also adapt the window.FormData method in order to ajaxify the upload process, and update the image onSuccess with the server source.

http://examples.torntech.com/ajax_file/

HTML:

```
       <div id="wrapper">
            <form id="ajaxFileForm" method="post" action="processFile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input id="imageToUpload" name="file" type="file"><br>
                <input name="somefield" type="text" value="Hello World"><br>
                <button id="previewBtn" type="button" disabled="">Preview</button>
                <button id="uploadBtn" type="submit" disabled="">Upload</button>
            </form>
            <div id="previewWrapper">
                <h4>Preview Image:</h4>
                <img style="display:none;" src="/assets/img/pixel.gif" id="preview" alt="Image Preview">
                <div id="info"></div>
            </div>
            <hr style="height:1px; border:0; background: #666;">
            <div id="responseWrapper" style="display: none">
                <h4>Response:</h4>
                <div id="output"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
//<![CDATA[
        Request.implement({
            options: {
                form: null
            },
            sendFile: function(options){
                if (!this.check(options)) return this;

                this.options.isSuccess = this.options.isSuccess || this.isSuccess;
                this.running = true;

                var type = typeOf(options);
                if (type == 'string' || type == 'element') options = {data: options};

                var old = this.options;
                options = Object.append({data: old.data, url: old.url, method: old.method, form: old.form, sendAsBinary: old.sendAsBinary}, options);
                var data = options.data, url = String(options.url);

                if (!url) url = document.location.pathname;

                var trimPosition = url.lastIndexOf('/');
                if (trimPosition > -1 && (trimPosition = url.indexOf('#')) > -1) url = url.substr(0, trimPosition);

                if (this.options.noCache)
                    url += (url.contains('?') ? '&' : '?') + String.uniqueID();

                var xhr = this.xhr;
                xhr.open("POST", url, this.options.async, this.options.user, this.options.password);
                if (this.options.user && 'withCredentials' in xhr) xhr.withCredentials = true;

                xhr.onreadystatechange = this.onStateChange.bind(this);

                Object.each(this.headers, function(value, key){
                    try {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader(key, value);
                    } catch (e){
                        this.fireEvent('exception', [key, value]);
                    }
                }, this);

                this.fireEvent('request');
                if(options.form){
                    data = new FormData();
                    options.form.getChildren('input').each(function(el){
                        var name = el.get('name'),
                        value = (el.get('type') == 'file')? el.files[0] : el.get('value');
                        data.append(name, value);
                    });
                }
                xhr.send(data);
                if (!this.options.async) this.onStateChange();
                if (this.options.timeout) this.timer = this.timeout.delay(this.options.timeout, this);
                return this;
            }
        });

        addEvent('domready', function(){
            var preview = $('preview'),
            output = $('output'),
            info = $('info'),
            previewWrapper = $('previewWrapper'),
            responseWrapper = $('responseWrapper'),
            previewBtn = $('previewBtn'),
            imageToUpload = $('imageToUpload'),
            wrapper = $('wrapper'),
            uploadBtn = $('uploadBtn'),
            bothBtns = new Elements([uploadBtn, previewBtn]),
            isFileReader = true,
            fileTypes = {
                'jpeg' : true,
                'png' : true,
                'bmp' : true,
                'jpg': true
            },
            fileToUpload = null,
            maxSize =   2986000,
            initReader = function(){
                if(!isFileReader)
                    return false;
                var reader = new FileReader();
                //Chrome doesn't initiatize this - so onload only occurs when the object is created.
                reader.onload = function () {
                    preview.set('src', reader.result);
                    preview.setStyle('display', 'inline');
                };
                return reader;
            },
            testFile = function(fileToUpload){
                if(!(fileTypes[fileToUpload.type.replace('image/', '')])){
                    alert('Please select a valid image.');
                    return false;
                }
                if(fileToUpload.size > maxSize){
                    alert('Filesize limit of ' + maxSize + ' exceeded.');
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            },
            getPreview = function(e){
                bothBtns.set('disabled', 'disabled');
                preview.set('src', '/assets/img/pixel.gif');

                fileToUpload = $('imageToUpload').files[0];
                if(!fileToUpload)
                    return true;

                info.set('html', '<ul><li><strong>'+ fileToUpload.name + '</strong> (' + (fileToUpload.type || 'N/A') + ') ' + fileToUpload.size + ' bytes</li></ul>');
                if(testFile(fileToUpload)){
                    bothBtns.removeProperty('disabled');
                    var reader = initReader();
                    if(!reader)
                        return true;
                    reader.readAsDataURL(fileToUpload);
                    if(e && e.type != 'submit'){
                        var scroll = previewWrapper.getPosition().y;
                        scrollFx.start(0, scroll);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },
            scrollFx = new Fx.Scroll(window, {wheelStops: false}),
            myRequest = new Request({
                url: 'processFile.php',
                headers: {
                    'Sender' : 'XMLHttpRequest'
                },
                onRequest: function(){
                    output.set('html', "<p>Loading...</p>");
                    var scroll = responseWrapper.getPosition().y;
                    scrollFx.start(0, scroll);
                },
                onSuccess: function(text){
                    var scroll = responseWrapper.getPosition().y;
                    scrollFx.start(0, scroll);
                    output.set('html', text);
                }
            });

            if(typeof(window.FormData) === 'undefined'){
                $$('#ajaxFileForm, hr, #responseWrapper').dispose();
                wrapper.set('html', '<p>Your browser does not support FormData - For XHR File Uploads</p>');
                return;
            }
            if(typeof(window.FileReader) === 'undefined'){
                isFileReader = false;
                previewBtn.dispose();
                previewWrapper.set('html', '<p>Your browser does not support File API - For Previews</p>');
            }
            $('ajaxFileForm').addEvent('submit', function(e){
                e.stop();
                if(!getPreview(e))
                    return false;
                responseWrapper.setStyle('display', 'block');
                var formData = $('ajaxFileForm');
                myRequest.sendFile({form: formData});
            });
            imageToUpload.addEvent('change', getPreview);
            previewBtn.addEvent('click', getPreview);
            getPreview();
        });
        //]]>
```

Comment: seems like a good solution even though im not sure how I should integrate it with my code :/ Im uploading the picture to my database after a submit form is clicked

Comment: What are you using the "text" input field to?

Comment: just an extra field to show that it works with multiple form fields, so it's not limited to just files

Comment: you could use the actual code and include the mootools library on your page, less work for you. Otherwise you would have to try to translate it from Mootools Syntax to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try it please.

### HTML:

```
<form runat="server">
    <input type="file" id="imgInput">
    <img src="#" alt="image" id="img">
</form>
```

### JavaScript:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#img').attr('src', e.target.result;)
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$('#imgInput').change(function() {
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: I would like to avoid using FileReader()